# javascript json object with objects inside

Tags: javascript, json

I have a JavaScript code.

```
var a = {'a': 5};
var b = {'b': 6};
var c = {a, b}; // produces an error
```

How can I create such object, so that I can refer to it like c.a and it gives me required data?

Comment: what is required data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are trying to do this:

```
var a = {'a': 5};
var b = {'b': 6};
var c = {'a':a, 'b':b}; 
console.log(c.a)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var a = {'a': 5};
var b = {'b': 6};
var c = {a, b};

c.a = a;
c.a.a === 5; // true

c = {
  a: {'a': 5},
  b: 6
};
c.a.a === 5; // true
```